# How do you store two pieces of info about a user when you have multiple users in c

Tags: c, arrays

i dont really have much experience with c but how would i go about storing two pieces of info about a user when you have multiple users in c. Im getting player name and player type. I need to shuffle them individually e.g. sort names alphabetically etc. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Array of structures. I'll leave the google-fu to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a record type:

```
typedef struct Info_s {
   char  n[6];
   int   a;
   int   b;
} Info_t;
```

Define an array type:

```
typedef Info_t allInfo_t[12];
```

Declare a variable of that type:

```
allInfo_t myInfo;
```

Take a look at [qsort()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/) to maintain the array sorted and [bsearch()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/bsearch/) to search quickly into the array. Don't forget to implement a function to compare `Info_t`.

Comment: Thanks a mill! I was thinking it was that but I was hoping there was a simpler way of doing it thanks